# CSS/Javascript Create Input with Border-Bottom

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, input

I would like to know how to create an input with a border-bottom changing color depending if the input is filled with text or not.

Here is an example (Hoshi): http://tympanus.net/Development/TextInputEffects/

I need to do the exact same thing as that "Hoshi" example. Has someone ever done that?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: So why you took all the effort to post it as a question? you can easily download that code and use it.

Comment: i didn't knew how to do that, i'm sorry

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Go to [Your example](http://tympanus.net/Development/TextInputEffects/)

And make Ctrl-U everything you need is visible

Comment: It should be a comment not an answer.

Comment: I can't comment @vivekkupadhyay